# how to add Folder directory or files in a folder to JTree of my code, before answering check the code that I written

Tags: java, swing, jtree

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class Selectionpage {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selection Page");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Vector groupVector = new Vector();
        Vector Forms = new Vector();
        Forms.add("Forms");
        Forms.add("form1");
        Forms.add("form2");
        Forms.add("form3");
        Forms.add("form4");

        Vector Reports = new Vector();
        Reports.add("Reports");
        Reports.add("report1");
        Reports.add("report2");
        Reports.add("report3");
        Reports.add("report4");

        groupVector.add(Forms);
        groupVector.add(Reports);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

        for (int i = 0; i < groupVector.size(); i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
                    new CheckBoxNode(((Vector) groupVector.elementAt(i)).elementAt(0).toString(), false));
            for (int j = 1; j < ((Vector) groupVector.elementAt(i)).size(); j++) {
                node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(
                        new CheckBoxNode(((Vector) groupVector.elementAt(i)).elementAt(j).toString(), false)));
            }
            rootNode.add(node);
        }

        JTree tree = new JTree(rootNode);
        tree.setToggleClickCount(1);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "None");
        CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        tree.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree));
        tree.setEditable(true);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Submit")) {
                    System.out.println("Button has been clicked");
                }
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(submit, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode) {
            public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
                Object currNode = path.getLastPathComponent();
                super.valueForPathChanged(path, newValue);
                if ((currNode != null) && (currNode instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode editedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) currNode;
                    CheckBoxNode newCBN = (CheckBoxNode) newValue;

                    if (!editedNode.isLeaf()) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < editedNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) editedNode.getChildAt(i);
                            CheckBoxNode cbn = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
                            cbn.setSelected(newCBN.isSelected());
                        }
                    } else {
                        boolean isAllChiledSelected = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i < editedNode.getParent().getChildCount(); i++) {
                            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) editedNode.getParent().getChildAt(i);
                            CheckBoxNode cbn = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
                            if (!cbn.isSelected()) {
                                isAllChiledSelected = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isAllChiledSelected) {
                            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) editedNode.getParent();
                            CheckBoxNode cbn = (CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject();
                            cbn.setSelected(isAllChiledSelected);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!newCBN.isSelected()) {
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) editedNode.getParent();
                        if (node.getUserObject() instanceof CheckBoxNode)
                            ((CheckBoxNode) node.getUserObject()).setSelected(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private JCheckBox leafRenderer = new JCheckBox();

    private DefaultTreeCellRenderer nonLeafRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();

    Color selectionBorderColor, selectionForeground, selectionBackground,
            textForeground, textBackground;

    protected JCheckBox getLeafRenderer() {
        return leafRenderer;
    }

    public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() {
        Font fontValue;
        fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
        if (fontValue != null) {
            leafRenderer.setFont(fontValue);
        }
        Boolean booleanValue = (Boolean) UIManager
                .get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
        leafRenderer.setFocusPainted((booleanValue != null)
                && (booleanValue.booleanValue()));

        selectionBorderColor = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBorderColor");
        selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
        selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
        textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
        textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
            boolean hasFocus) {

        Component returnValue;

        String stringValue = tree.convertValueToText(value, selected,
                expanded, leaf, row, false);
        leafRenderer.setText(stringValue);
        leafRenderer.setSelected(false);

        leafRenderer.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());

        if (selected) {
            leafRenderer.setForeground(selectionForeground);
            leafRenderer.setBackground(selectionBackground);
        } else {
            leafRenderer.setForeground(textForeground);
            leafRenderer.setBackground(textBackground);
        }

        if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
            Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value)
                    .getUserObject();
            if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                leafRenderer.setText(node.getText());
                leafRenderer.setSelected(node.isSelected());
            }
        }
        returnValue = leafRenderer;
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

    CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();

    ChangeEvent changeEvent = null;

    JTree tree1;

    DefaultMutableTreeNode editedNode;

    public CheckBoxNodeEditor(JTree tree) {
        this.tree1 = tree;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        JCheckBox checkbox = renderer.getLeafRenderer();
        CheckBoxNode checkBoxNode = new CheckBoxNode(checkbox.getText(),
                checkbox.isSelected());
        return checkBoxNode;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
            TreePath path = tree1.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(),
                    mouseEvent.getY());
            if (path != null) {
                Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
                if ((node != null) && (node instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                    editedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node;
                    Object userObject = editedNode.getUserObject();
                    Rectangle r = tree1.getPathBounds(path);
                    int x = mouseEvent.getX() - r.x;
                    int y = mouseEvent.getY() - r.y;
                    JCheckBox checkbox = renderer.getLeafRenderer();
                    checkbox.setText("");
                    returnValue = userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode && x > 0 && x < checkbox.getPreferredSize().width;
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(final JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

        Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                true, expanded, leaf, row, true);

        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                tree.repaint();
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        };

        if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
            ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
        }

        return editor;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNode {
    String text;

    boolean selected;

    public CheckBoxNode(String text, boolean selected) {
        this.text = text;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean newValue) {
        selected = newValue;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String newValue) {
        text = newValue;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[" + text + "/" + selected + "]";
    }
}
```

and my output is:[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb5b9.png)
In Place of form1,form2,form3,form4 and report1,report2,report3,report4 need to display my files in the folder directory check boxes must and should.

In Place of form1,form2,form3,form4 and report1,report2,report3,report4 need to display my files in the folder directory check boxes must and should.

Comment: The last sentence in your question makes no sense to me. Do you want to display a directory hierarchy tree as a `JTree`? By the way, `JTree` allows multiple selection by highlighting. Are you sure that you need the check boxes to indicate whether a given `JTree` node is selected?

Comment: yes exactly that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswing%5D+jtree+directory+file

Comment: not helpful, the link shared showing only directory

Comment: The link is to a search result containing 76 stackoverflow questions regarding using a `JTree` to display a directory hierarchy - and none of them helped you?

Comment: yes, not found anything helpful:(